# Confused about Nexus 7 failing system update to 4.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7, ota-update, 4.2-jelly-bean

During the day today, I got the notification about the available system update to 4.2. SO I confirmed it after ensuring that SuperSU was set to "survival mode" and then it looked like it was actually doing the update. However, when I now check the system version it states 4.1.2 just like it did before. I also rebooted once more in between just in case something wasn't complete or so.

Any ideas? How can I force the update through. There was no indication that anything went wrong during the update, yet I am stuck at 4.1.2 and checking for available updates shows none.

Note: I have encrypted the contents of the tablet (standard option). Can that be an issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out with the Nexus Root Toolkit in the end. However, I didn't get around scrapping the existing contents this way. So what I did was to back up all my data and applications and then flash a new stock ROM (4.2.1). This worked fine, but it means I needed to re-encrypt the device and restore from the backup whatever I wanted.

So it was more tedious than expected, but well worth it in hindsight. Especially the multi-user system is worth it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem and have not encrypted my nexus 7's storage (but it is rooted). Any luck? I've attempted to update it several times with no success.

To reset the "check for updates" and allow you to attempt the update again, try the following:
In Settings > Apps > All (tab), search for Google Services Framework, clear it's data and kill it. Then go to Settings > About tablet > System Update, and it will find the update.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fixed by full reset and manual flash by fastboot, but all data need to backed up and restored.

**Don't flash system partition only, or you will get bootloop!**
There's not caused by encription, but maybe by SuperSU (not tested, because of rooting-unrootng for me was need more time, than clean install and configure for 2 users).

P.S. And get ready, what some apps not working with secondary users - I have crashes with Tapatalk, for example...